# How to notify adapter by position with multiple view type

Tags: android

I have an Adapter which has multiple view type {Profile, About, Photo, Friend and Timeline}. After I request to service success for those type, I want to notify adapter by position. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Sophara, why don't you try calling notifyDataSetChanged(), once you get a new data? Calling notifyDataSetChanged() would update the corresponding data in the view.

Comment: I've tried like that, but view will be take long time to display as it wait for all service request to be finish and notifydatasetchange once at time. My idea is, if we have get success service of profile, we need to notify it and notify other next.

Comment: if you want to notify adapter to re-draw and re-bind data at particular position , you can call mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position) of adapter method

Comment: Why would you wait for all the service request to complete? Your each call should asynchronous and once you have response data in any of them, you should update the corresponding view only.